# Having issue with getting value from object variable. No errors showing

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I created an array called animals containing two objects. I want to get a value from the name variable in the object animals and insert that value in a return statement in the map method. I used ${} to access the variable.

```js
const Animals = [{
    name: "Lion",
    type: "Carnivore",
  },
  {
    name: "Cow",
    type: "Herbivore",
  },
];


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let display = Animals.map(function(item) {
    return '<h1>${item.name}</h1>';
  });
  console.log(display);
});
```

Now I'm supposed to get in the console an array of two items containing the values of the variables -- the result should look like this `['<h1>Lion</h1>', '<h1>Cow</h1>']`. But instead I get this `['<h1>${item.name}</h1>', '<h1>${item.name}</h1>']`. As you can clearly see, for some reason the ${} was unable to access the variable and get the value. I don't know why this's happening. Console log shows no errors. Plz help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your code instead of:

```
'<h1>${item.name}</h1>'
```

Should be:

```
`<h1>${item.name}</h1>`
```

Here is the documentation for [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Demo:

```js
const Animals = [{
    name: "Lion",
    type: "Carnivore",
  },
  {
    name: "Cow",
    type: "Herbivore",
  },
]

const display = Animals.map(({ name }) => `<h1>${name}</h1>`)

console.log(display)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside `${...}` structures are [template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax but in order for them to work they need to be enclosed with backticks instead of single/double quotes.

```js
const animals=[{name:"Lion",type:"Carnivore"},{name:"Cow",type:"Herbivore"}];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const display = animals.map(function(item) {
    return `<h1>${item.name}</h1>`;
  });
  console.log(display);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Animals = [{
    name: "Lion",
    type: "Carnivore",
  },
  {
    name: "Cow",
    type: "Herbivore",
  },
];


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let display = Animals.map(function(item) {
   return '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>';
  // return `<h1>${item.name}</h1>`;
  });
  console.log(display);
});
```